# Conditional statements in makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

I've a directive defined in C++ code _2G_MYSQL_ which includes other mysql files when defined.
And I want to use specific libraries only when this token is defined in the code. Is there a way to so this in Makefile.

something like,

ifdef _2G_MYSQL_
LIBS = -lstdc++ -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lm -lMst_main -lAMR_Reject_DSP -lFalseReject -lMStream_setting
else
LIBS = -lm -lMst_main -lAMR_Reject_DSP -lFalseReject -lMStream_setting
endif

This obviously doesnt work because the token is in the header file and not in the makefile. Any suggestions ? Thank you !

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to build the executable using libraries, and you want the choice of libraries to depend on a preprocessor macro defined in a header file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, thats right ! :-)

Comment: There has to be a way to be able to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `gcc` (and the usual text tools), you could do it in the following way:

```
 SYMBOL=_2G_MYSQL_
 MAINFILE=myfile.c

 CHECK=$(shell gcc -E -dD $(MAINFILE) | grep $(SYMBOL))

 ifeq ($(findstring define $(SYMBOL), $(CHECK)),define $(SYMBOL))
     LIBS=-lstdc++ -lmysqlclient ....
 else
      LIBS=-lm -lMst_main ...
 endif
```

Comment: This doesnt work but i think im doing something wrong. Should the MAINFILE be the header file in which the symbol is defined ?

Comment: It could be the header or a c file that includes the header. Check, if `gcc -E -dD` works; it should produce all `#define`s

Comment: Yes gcc -E -dD works, but the ifeq condition never satisfies. Thanks, im workign on it, this should work